# OutOfMemoryError и Html.fromHtml in textview

Tags: android, json, textview

Всем добрый день.
Пишу приложение для сайта. Смысл простой. С APi сайта в формате JSON скачиваем все материалы. А потом из базы данных показываем пользователю. Но подкралась проблема откуда не ждал. При открытии материала с 1-10 картинками вроде бы всё нормально. Но бывают материалы, где изображений очень много. бывает более 50. И на этом этапе приложение закрывается из-за нехватки памяти устройства. Ниже код Активности в которой должно происходить отображение.

```
public class FullTextActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  Html.ImageGetter {
TextView  tv;
WebView ww;
TextView content;
private final static String TAG = "TestImageGetter";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_text);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

    tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));


    Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(getIntent().getStringExtra("content"), this, null);
   tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    tv.setText(spanned);
}

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
    Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

    new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

    return d;
}

class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String sourceT = (String) params[0];

        String source = sourceT.replace("../..", "http://mediananny.com");

        mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground " + source);
        try {
            InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute drawable " + mDrawable);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute bitmap " + bitmap);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            mDrawable.setLevel(1);
            // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
            // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
            CharSequence t = tv.getText();
            tv.setText(t);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Для понимания все глубины трагедии показываю, что именно надо отобразить в приложении http://mediananny.com/reportazhi/2309660/

а вот что я имею из API
    http://mediananny.com/api/category/?offset=0&category_id=83&debug=true

Comment: Возможно кто-то подскажет другой путь реализации? Приходит мысль использовать WebView. Но есть загвоздка: там адрес картинки представлен, как ../../content/images_new/news/original/115746.jpg, т.е. без указания домена

Comment: WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl).   При помощи этого метода можно использовать не полные, а относительные ссылки. В baseUrl нужно передать базовый URL, где лежат картинки

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал следующим образом:

1. Вытащил ссылки на изображения. Если оффлайн работа не нужна, то сразу к п.3
2. Скачал бы на устройства изображения, как файлы, не читая полностью их в память и сохранил, где нужно, путь до изображения на устройстве.
3. Для отображения использовал бы одну из библиотек:

   - [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html#_) от фэйсбука
   - [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)
   - старая добрая [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Они умеют грузить изображения как с тэрнета, кэшируюя их, или же напрямую с девайса. И не нужно будет беспокоиться о съеденной памяти.

Что касается отображения всего контента прямо в `TextView`, то я бы не стал так делать. Вы же пишете для конкретного сайтика, можно заточиться для него. Выбрать ключевые элементы для отображения и использовать `ListView` или `RecyclerView`.

Более подробно подход описан [**тут**](http://habrahabr.ru/company/surfingbird/blog/242911/)

Comment: Так. спасибо всем ответившим. Теперь ситуация как то прояснилась. Последний вопрос. Как новичку в этом деле не совсем понятно. У меня получилось отобразить данный контент в WebView. И даже всё красиво показывает. Насколько такое решение хорошее? какие плюсы и минусы. И стоит ли таки заморочиться и следую советам таки сделать используя библиотеки и не использовать готового WebView

Comment: логика работы с WebView на первый взгляд проще, потому что вам нужно сгенерить html и все. Но такой подход со временем будет становиться сложнее и сложнее для кастомизации. Вы не сможете управлять всеми элементами и памятью. Скорость работы будет не такой, как хочется. Я делал подобное и сразу же воспользовался предложенным мной вариантом.

Answer (score 0):

В WebView отображайте, а еще лучше в ListView.

> Но есть загвоздка: там адрес картинки представлен, как
>   ../../content/images_new/news/original/115746.jpg, т.е. без указания
>   домена

Раз TextView может отобразить картинки то и WebView сможет.

Comment: При использовании стандартного парсера HTML.ImageGet я могу эту строку менять, убирая из начала двоеточия со слешами и заменяя их адресом сайта. А как в WebView дать правильную строку. Тем более что их там много.

Comment: WebView можно скормить просто html файл.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема известная. Ее корень в:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Много битмапов сильно едят память. Раньше был такое флажок в `BitmapFactory.Options` `inPurgeable=true`, который позволял битмапы выгружать на диск в случае нехватки памяти. В новых версиях ее депрекировали, но вроде должна быть ее замена. Почитайте внимательно доку на класс [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) - там много разных параметров и флажков, с помощью которых можно отрегулировать настройки генерации битмапов.

**Update**

Можно попробовать еще применить [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Если будет много битмапов одновременно, оно все равно ляжет с OOMe, тут нужно подход менять в принципе.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Answer (score 0):

При загрузке изображений извне всегда надо их масштабировать
Пример кода:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
InputStream in = null;
try {
    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
    in.close();



    int scale = 1;
    while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > 
          IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
       scale++;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", 
       orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

    Bitmap b = null;
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
    if (scale > 1) {
        scale--;
        // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
        // larger than target
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = scale;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

        // resize to desired dimensions
        int height = b.getHeight();
        int width = b.getWidth();
        Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ",
           height: " + height);

        double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                / (((double) width) / height));
        double x = (y / height) * width;

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x, 
           (int) y, true);
        b.recycle();
        b = scaledBitmap;

        System.gc();
    } else {
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    }
    in.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "bitmap size - width: " +b.getWidth() + ", height: " + 
       b.getHeight());
    return b;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
    return null;
}
```

взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8497703/2293954)

PS: лучше использовать готовые библиотеки, в которых это уже решено (перечислены в комментариях)

Comment: А лучше не изобраттаь велосипед а воспользоваться ImageLoader - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader или Glide

Comment: или [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: Я бы поостерегся от столь категоричного:

*при загрузке изображений извне всегда надо их масштабировать*

Comment: @Barmaley даже одной картинкой с огромным разрешением можно уронить в OOM. Лучше считать внешний источник изображений недоверенным по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите ещё главу 
[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
.
Там описано, как рассчитать параметр [BitmapOptions.inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize), чтобы сэкономить память при декодировании больших изображений, если не хотите использовать готовые библиотеки.

При 50 изображениях в одном TextView вы, скорее всего, все равно упретесь в память. По хорошему, нужно выгружать из памяти изображения, которые сейчас не на экране.
Можно ещё установить `android:largeHeap`, чтобы приложению было доступно больше памяти.

Answer (score 0):

И так, здравствуйте всем снова. Опять встала эта же проблема. Я в своё время использовал обычный WebView. но теперь нужн жто всё красиво отобразить в TextView. А посему. прочитав все коментарии, я понял как достать картинки. Но не могу понять как входящий текст разбить на куски, что бы организовать ListView. Ведь, как я понял, должнын получится некий список "кусок текста - картинка - кусок текста"